# When you don't phrase a question well

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522037/when-is-the-support-function-of-a-set-strictly-subbaditive). I asked for a "sufficient condition", but of course, I had in mind a certain kind of answer, as it's trivial to find "some sufficient condition" for any statement. The problem is, I got an answer that didn't satisfy me, but I can see how other people would see it as a bona fide answer. I then edited the question to make clear what I was looking for.

What's the right approach in this case? Accept the answer and ask the question again, clarified? Or edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Accept, ask again, and make a link to your previous question. Specify how a new answer should be different.

Answer (score 6):

It's a judgement call. If the given answer was utterly trivial, it might make more sense to edit your question and hope the author of the answer deletes it (or ask them to do so). If the answer was thoughtful and carefully presented, then yes, it would probably be better to accept it and ask a new question.